# Laravel Corcel WooCommerce - Add product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, woocommerce, corcel

I am using the laravel package "corcel/woocommerce" and I am trying to attach product categories to the created product.

```
        $product = Product::create([
                'post_title' => 'Product name',
                'post_content' => 'Post description',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'product'
                ]
        );
        $product->createMeta([
            '_sku' => '1234',
            '_regular_price' => '10.00',
            '_sale_price' => '5.00',
            '_thumbnail_id' => 10
            // other wp_postmeta product meta values...
        ]);
```

Here is where I am trying to add a category:

```
$product->categories()->create([
'cat_name' => 'Test'
]);
```

But I get the following error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException 

  Add [cat_name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [Corcel\WooCommerce\Model\ProductCategory][.][1]
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can attach a WooCommerce category to the product please?

Answer (score 1):

in your model `ProductCategory` you should define the $fillable attribute to support [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
class ProductCategory extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['cat_name']; // not only cat_name but also all fillable attributes
}
```

if you can't change the ProductCategory model, the change the way you save it:

```
$productCategory= new ProductCategory();
$productCategory->cat_name='test'; // if the is another required attributes, fill them.
$productCategory->save();
$product->categories()->attach($productCategory->id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. `ProductCategory` is within the Corcel package and when I changed this, it didn't work unfortunately. I believe this would be good if I wasnt using the package.

Comment: I suggest then changing the way you create ProductCategory, try the update answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, unfortunately this didnt work. I know normally in Laravel this would work. I have left an issue request on the [github repo](https://github.com/corcel/woocommerce/issues/21). I didnt know if anyone had used this package before.